# Reuse element from Spark SQL query inside its subquery

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, subquery

I am writing a Spark SQL, like this

```
select 
 colA, # possible values "A" and "B"
 colB,
 count(*) / (select count(*) from table_3 where colA = "A") as colC_A,
 count(*) / (select count(*) from table_3 where colA = "B") as colC_B,
from 
 table_1 a 
join 
 table_2 b on 
  a.colA = b.colA and 
  a.colB = b.colB 
group by 
  colA, colB
```

I want to do something like this, to avoid unnecessary extra columns

```
select 
 colA, # line x
 colB,
 count(*) / (select count(*) from table_3 where colA = a.colA) as colC # line y
from 
 table_1 a 
join 
 table_2 b on 
  a.colA = b.colA and 
  a.colB = b.colB 
group by 
  colA, colB
```

Whatever the value is in line x, I want to use that in the `where` clause of line y.
Is it somehow possible? This strictly needs to be a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data - employee

```
#
# 1 - Create sample employee data
#


# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
    (1,"Smith",-1,"2018",10,"M",300000),
    (2,"Rose",1,"2010",20,"M",225000),
    (3,"Williams",2,"2010",30,"M",100000),
    (4,"Brown",2,"2010",30,"F",125000),
    (5,"Jones",1,"2010",50,"F",250000),
    (6,"Headrick",5,"2010",50,"F",175000),
    (7,"Murphy",5,"2010",50,"F",150000) 
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["emp_id","name","superior_emp_id","branch_id","dept_id","gender","salary"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# create table
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("employees")
```

Sample Data - Departments

```
#
# 2 - Create sample department data
#

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
    ("Finance",10,"2018"),
    ("Marketing",20,"2010"),
    ("Marketing",20,"2018"),
    ("Sales",30,"2005"),
    ("Sales",30,"2010"),
    ("IT",50,"2010")
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["dept_name","dept_id","branch_id"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# create table
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("departments")
```

Sample Data - Anonymous Donations by Department

```
#
# 3 - Create sample donations
#

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
    (10,"100"),
    (20,"75"),
    (20,"75"),
    (30,"150"),
    (30,"50"),
    (30,"150"),
    (50,"75"),
    (50,"150"),
    (50,"150"),
    (50,"75")
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["dept_id","donation_usd"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# create table
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("donations")
```

This query fails!

[image]

```
%sql
select 
  e.dept_id, 
  e.branch_id,
  count(*) as employees,
  (select count(*) from donations as m where m.dept_id = e.dept_id) as total_donations
from 
  employees as e 
left join 
  departments as d
on 
  e.dept_id = d.dept_id and e.branch_id = d.branch_id
group by
  e.dept_id, 
  e.branch_id
```

Replace the correlated sub query with a CTE and join on the department id.

```
%sql
with cte_data as
(
  select dept_id, count(*) as donation_cnt from donations group by dept_id
) 
select 
  e.dept_id, 
  e.branch_id,
  first(c.donation_cnt) as donation,
  count(*) as employees
from 
  employees as e 
left join 
  departments as d
on 
  e.dept_id = d.dept_id and e.branch_id = d.branch_id
left join
  cte_data as c on c.dept_id = e.dept_id
group by
  e.dept_id, 
  e.branch_id
```

This query works!

[image]